# Field inside a conductor is non zero at a point away from the center when I provided two electrons to a hollow spherical conductor?

Tags: electrostatics, charge

I searched everywhere and found that Net Electric Field inside a conductor is **always** zero when there is no charge inside it but then to convince myself I just tried to prove it and gave two electrons to a conductor and as to minimize repulsion they will be separated by **twice the radius of sphere**.

I took the radius of sphere to be **5 meter** and found field at a point **2 meter away from one electron** and found it be **non - zero**.
Why is it so?

Here is the calculations : [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I took the radius of sphere to be 5 meter and found field at a point 2 meter away from one electron and found it be non - zero. Why is it so?

It is so because in your analysis you did not account for the fact that all of the other electrons in the conductor will move in response to your addition of the two electrons. In other words, you called the sphere a conductor, but then mathematically you treated it like an insulator with fixed charges.

To verify that this is the problem, calculate the E field actually on the sphere itself. You will find that it has a transverse component. Being a conductor that transverse component will produce a current, thereby redistributing the charge. In the end, you will have a uniform charge density all around the sphere.

Answer (score 0):

A metal the shell consists of positive ions locked in position within a lattice and free/mobile electrons.

If you add your two electrons and they are fixed in position outside or within the body of the conducting shell, who knows how?!, then the charges within the conductor will rearrange themselves so that there is no electric field within the conductor and no electric field in the region inside the inner surface of the metal shell.
If those two electrons are placed to be on the inside surface of the metal conductor then there may well be an electric field in the region inside the inner surface of the metal shell.

Comment: Ohh, silly me! Got it.